# Select query won't give expected result in linux script

Tags: sql, linux, sybase

I am trying the retrieve the data which have the special character (') single quote.

My query is

```
select * from table_name nolock WHERE value LIKE "%'%" and col_value = 1
```

I am connecting to the database through Linux script and trying to execute the above query in SYBASE DB.

While using below query getting Syntax error

```
select * from table_name nolock WHERE value LIKE "%'%" and col_value = 1
```

While using below query Getting no result

```
select * from table_name nolock WHERE value LIKE \"\%\'\%\" and col_value = 1
```

Comment: ANSI SQL has ' as string delimiters. E.g. LIKE '%xyz%'. If ' character needed string, enter it twice, e.g. LIKE '%''%'

Comment: As per your suggestion i have used the query like below.

{select * from table_name nolock WHERE value LIKE '%''%' and col_value = 1}

And the script executed it like below. But stilll no result.

{+ select * from table_name nolock WHERE value LIKE '\''%'\'''\''%'\'' and col-value = 1'}

Answer (score -1):

The scape character for sybase is [' (single quote)], your query will run if you write:

```
select * from table_name nolock WHERE value LIKE "%''%" and col_value = 1
```